# Override method_missing for class and instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a general purpose module to apply the method_missing pattern for dynamic method creation to some of my Rails models.  These models have both class methods and instance methods.  While I can write a module fairly straightforwardly for either the class case:

```
  module ClassVersion
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
        if meth.to_s =~ /^(.+)_async$/
          Async::handle_async self, $1, *args, &block
        else
          super meth, *args, &block
        end
      end

      # Logic for this method MUST match that of the detection in method_missing
      def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
        Async::async?(method_name) || super
      end
    end
  end
```

or the instance case:

```
  module InstanceVersion
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
      if meth.to_s =~ /^(.+)_async$/
        Async::handle_async self, $1, *args, &block
      else
        super meth, *args, &block
      end
    end

    # Logic for this method MUST match that of the detection in method_missing
    def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
      Async::async?(method_name) || super
    end
  end
```

... I can't seem to support both cases in the same class.  Is there a better way to override method_missing such that both cases are supported?  I'm on Rails 3.2....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is pretty straightforward, and unusual at the same time. `ActiveSupport::Concern` is giving you possibility of defining nested `ClassMethods` module that is extending base class on `included` module hook. Usually this is handy, because you don't want to augment both class and its instances with the same methods.

What you need to do is stop using `ActiveSupport::Concern` and write `included` hook to meet your particular needs:

```
module AsyncModule
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    if meth.to_s =~ /^(.+)_async$/
      Async::handle_async self, $1, *args, &block
    else
      super meth, *args, &block
    end
  end

  # Logic for this method MUST match that of the detection in method_missing
  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    Async::async?(method_name) || super
  end

  private

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend self
  end
end
```

Comment: Simple and elegant.  Thanks!

Comment: it seems that the key is: if you add a `method_missing` to a class via a module, you must also supply the `respond_to_missing?` for the module, otherwise the `method_missing` does not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following

```
  module ClassAndInstanceVersion
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
      self.class.method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    end

    def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
      self.class.respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
        if meth.to_s =~ /^(.+)_async$/
          Async::handle_async self, $1, *args, &block
        else
          super meth, *args, &block
        end
      end

      # Logic for this method MUST match that of the detection in method_missing
      def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
        Async::async?(method_name) || super
      end
    end
  end
```