# Where should I define method_missing in a Cucumber Ruby framework?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, metaprogramming, method-missing

I have a Ruby-Cucumber framework. I need to use the method `method_missing` to avoid writing a few repetitive functions. Where should I place my `method_missing`? In any `.rb` file under the `support` folder? Or should it go in some different specific file?

Comment: Try here: Post is titled: "Override method_missing for class and instance methods?" and you might get some ideas of how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846777/override-method-missing-for-class-and-instance-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `method_missing` like you would any Cucumber helper method, in an `.rb` file in the `support` directory and in a module which you then pass to [the Cucumber `World`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530123/what-object-is-in-play-for-instance-variables-i-e-what-is-self-in-cucumber-st/25541579#25541579):

```
module MethodMissing
  def method_missing(method)
    puts "You said #{method}"
  end
end
World MethodMissing
```

You can then call missing methods in step definitions.

Like any Cucumber helper method, `method_missing` should be defined only on the Cucumber `World`. If you defined it at the top level of the support file, it would be defined on the Ruby top-level object and available everywhere, which is unparsimonious and might break other code.

I deliberately didn't defer to `super`, since the `World` doesn't define `method_missing`, or define `respond_to_missing?`, since I didn't have any plans to call `method(:foo)` on the `World`, but you can do those things if you prefer to always do them when you define `method_missing`.